# Unable to fork children even after exiting previous ones

Tags: php, process, ps, fork

I have a CentOS VM on which I'm running a php socket server, that forks on every connection. The child process does its job and then exits.

The parent is also waiting to reap the dead zombie process (I have checked the `ps auxf` output)

`pcntl_wait($status, WNOHANG);` is executed after before every fork, so that cleans up 1 Zombie process (if any)

However, after a long run, the parent is unable to fork.

I think this is because of the `32768` limit.
The number of process in `ps -auxf` output are constantly around 750.

```
[root@test-machine ~]# cat /proc/self/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             119925               119925               processes
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       119925               119925               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us


[root@test-machine ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
```

**UPDATE:**
I checked the logs, and saw the error said `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in myfile.php`

The line it pointed to is the `pcntl_wait($status, WNOHANG);`, which is for waiting for a child process to terminate. The `WNOHANG` flag ensures that it does not hang, so if theres no exited child, it will continue the execution.

While the "Max Time" can be changed, something is causing `pcntl_wait` to loop.
I think something on the OS is making this happen. This is the socket that has maximum connections (I have multiple sockets, only this was affected)

Comment: What error you get when your app try to fork?

Comment: I'm not sure, the code had `exit` in it if there there was no pid after forking. I dont have access to logs right now.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev, I've added an update

Answer (score 0):

I checked [PHP documentation for function prcntl_wait](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php) and found this:

> **options**
>
> If wait3 is available on your system (mostly BSD-style systems), you
>   can provide the optional options parameter. If this parameter is not
>   provided, wait will be used for the system call. If wait3 is not
>   available, providing a value for options will have no effect. The
>   value of options is the value of zero or more of the following two
>   constants OR'ed together:

May be your OS doesn't have wait3 and this cause that issue. May be you could change function to `pcntl_waitpid` and this solve your issue.

Comment: No, if that was the case, the server would have frozen when there was no dead child, like it does when I don't specify `WNOHANG`. The issue I have posted does not happen everytime. It was running fine for 4 days, then it crashed.